# Selenium WebDriver ExtJS drop-down

Tags: extjs, selenium, automation, webdriver

I'm trying to find list of element in ExtJS drop-down. I found a good solution on stackoverflow, though it doesn't work for me.

Solution in C#:

```
 public void ClickComboItem(IWebElement input, string target)
        {
            input.Click();
            IList<IWebElement> comboItems = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class, 'x-combo-list') and contains(@style, 'visibility: hidden;')]//*[contains(@class, 'x-combo-list-item')]"));
            comboItems.First(item => item.Text.Trim() == target).Click();
        }
```

From [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BOLq.png).

Part which I need to automate look like this:

```
<div class="x-ie-shadow" id="ext-gen546" style="z-index: 12004; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(opacity=50) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=4); WIDTH: 351px; display: none; height: 301px; top: 186px; left: 1187px;"/>
<div class="x-layer x-combo-list " id="ext-gen544" style="z-index: 12005; position: absolute; width: 350px; height: 302px; visibility: hidden; font-size: 12px; top: -10000px; left: 0px;">
<div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="ext-gen545" style="width: 348px; height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
<div class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30813" viewIndex="0">
<div class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30813" viewIndex="1">
```

Actual click on the pointer is executed and I can see see drop-down list on the page, though comboItem returns '0' results. I assume I should adjust xPath correctly for my case, though it seems for me that it should work, as soon as structure is very similar with an example from the post I mentioned above.

Comment: can you paste the html code so that we can provide more relevant answers?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the xPath is not correct.

You gave "visibility: hidden;"

Try with ""visibility: visible;"

```
public void ClickComboItem(IWebElement input, string target)
{
    input.Click();
    IList<IWebElement> comboItems = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class, 'x-combo-list') and contains(@style, 'visibility: visible;')]//*[contains(@class, 'x-combo-list-item')]"));
    comboItems.First(item => item.Text.Trim() == target).Click();
}
```

Comment: I tried it as well. Unfortunately, doesn't work. As I can see I cannot find                                                                          //*[contains(@class, 'x-combo-list') and contains(@style, 'visibility: visible;')]                                                                                 Is there is any other possibility to find this element..?

Comment: @user1177636: Returned 0 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a different way without using Xpath

```
 IWebElement dvInner = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ext-gen545"));
 IList<IWebElement> comboItems = dvInner.FindElements(By.ClassName("x-combo-list-item"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement using stable id of any of the parent nodes.Basically using the xpath-axis concept.